# What regex can match a word, but only if that word is not part of a dot delimited chain of words?

Tags: .net, regex

For example, consider the following input:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Xyz.Data.TimeCard.SchedShift> SharpTop.DB.DL.wbpoc::GetSchedules(System.Int32,System.DateTime,System.DateTime)
```

The desired regex should match three strings:

1. `System.Int32`
2. `System.DateTime`
3. `System.DateTime`

No extra characters in the regex matches. No trailing commas or other.

The captures should be `Int32`, `DateTime` and `DateTime` respectively.

It should not match `System.Collections.Generic.List`

So, what is the end goal? Match all the type names directly in the System namespace and capture the bare type name.

The actual inputs are `Mono.Cecil.MemberReference.FullName` strings where the respective member reference can be method or field or type.

What I have currently is a trivial regex - `System\.(\w+)`. I loop in code over the matches and discard those followed by a dot. I would like to know if this discarding can be part of the regex.

The image below shows how the regex works on the aforementioned example. My after the match processing discards the first match (in red box) and accepts the other three.

[image]

It is important that matches do not match any trailing characters, so `System.Int32` is matched, but not `System.Int32,` or `System.Int32)` or `System.Int32[`, for example.

**EDIT**

Bohemian's answer is exactly what I needed. I have modified it slightly:

```
(?<!\.)\bSystem\.(\w+)\b(?!\.)
```

No way I would have thought of it by myself.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? What if you split the string by ".", if the first word is System and there are 2 words then remove "System.". Another approach would be to remove "System." and then if there are no periods left, keep the string.

Comment: I know I can do it like this. But I am curious about regex. Call it an academic exercise.

Comment: You need to completely rewrite your question making it clear on every point that you are looking for. You are at least 5 edits in and the question still isn't clear. I've had to completely redo my answer at least 3 times now due to this so I'm done with this question. It's too hard to paint a moving bus. Good luck.

Comment: @JeffC - You do not have to answer, of course. And I accept the critique. Would you be so kind to review the question after I have completely rewritten it? Your input is very valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a word boundary and a negative look ahead for a dot:

```
System\.(\w+)\b(?!\.)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Ck0m1X7Tf3MtOk).

The negative look ahead `(?!\.)` requires the next char to *not* be a dot.

The trick is to add a *word boundary* `\b`, so it doesn’t  allow the non-dot to be part of the word, ie to prevent it matching `System.fo` from `System.foo.bar` by treating the trailing `o` as the non-dot.

Comment: This is it! And very similar to the trivial regex I had with exactly the required addition. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead, ex:

```
(?<=System\.)\w+(?=[,\)])
```

Result:

1. Int32
2. DateTime
3. DateTime

**Update 2:** To get matches and captures:

```
(?<=[(,]).*?(?<=System.)(\w+)
```

Result:

```
Match 1: System.Int32
Group 1: Int32

Match 2: System.DateTime
Group 2: DateTime

Match 3: System.DateTime
Group 3: DateTime
```

**Update 3:** Regex without hardcoded non-alphabetic chars but then you have to exclude the first match and capture manually.

```
System\.(\w+)
```

Result:

```
Match 1: System.Collections
Group 1: Collections

Match 2: System.Int32
Group 2: Int32

Match 3: System.DateTime
Group 3: DateTime

Match 4: System.DateTime
Group 4: DateTime
```

Comment: It is close, but a little bit different from what I specify in the example. I want the `System.` part to be matched, but not captured. Does my example need some more clarification? I think I do say there what should be matched and what should be captured. Also, you hard code `,` and `)`, but method signatures can contain other characters after type names. It is just that my example shows off those two.

Comment: Updated regex with matches and captured groups.

Comment: This is almost perfect. Question - is it possible to avoid hard coding `(` and `,` ?

Comment: Yes, but then you have to exclude the first match and capture manually. See updated regex.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but accepted that of Bohemian, which nails it beautifully.